# MessageBoxButtons members in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

MessageBoxButtons class in System.Windows.Forms have this members:
OK, OKCancel, AbortRetryIgnore, YesNo, YesNoCancel, RetryCancel.

I write for Windows Phone and dont see this members. I see only OK and OKCancel: [image]
But OK and OKCancel its not what i need.
What should I do if I need the YesNo, or other buttons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could customise the message box, one particular implementation is shown in the following :-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271596/Customizing-MessageBox-on-Windows-Phone-7

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can customize the buttons text of the message box using the [Guide.BeginShowMessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940233%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) method from XNA, so no need to make a new control!

You can find a [MessageBoxService](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Phone-Toolkit/blob/master/src/Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit/Services/MessageBoxService.cs) on [Cimbalino Phone Windows Toolkit](http://cimbalino.org) if you are using MVVM architecture in your application